# xCode - add scroll event to UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, function, triggers, uiscrollview

I wrote an function that should do something when the top or bottom is hit with the UIScrollView.

```
    -(void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView*)scrolling
{
    NSLog(@"Event triggered.");
    float scrollViewHeight = scrolling.frame.size.height;
    float scrollContentSizeHeight = scrolling.contentSize.height;
    float scrollOffset = scrolling.contentOffset.y;

        if (scrollOffset == 0)
        {
            _lol.text = @"top hit";
            NSLog(@"Top Hit");
        }
        else if (scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight == scrollContentSizeHeight)
        {
            _lol.text = @"bottom hit";
            NSLog(@"bottom Hit");
        }
    }
```

The problem is: I have no idea how to link this function to my UIScrollView named "scrolling".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have scrollview named `mScrollView1`

To call use it as below

```
 [self scrollViewDidScroll:mScrollView1];
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^ here is your scrollview name
```

---

### Edit 1

This is what is used to handles all the edge cases for scrollview. You need an ivar to keep state, and as shown in the comments, there are other ways to handle this.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    //[super scrollViewWillBeginDragging:scrollView];   // pull to refresh

    self.isScrolling = YES;
    NSLog(@"+scrollViewWillBeginDragging");
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    //[super scrollViewDidEndDragging:scrollView willDecelerate:decelerate];    // pull to refresh

    if(!decelerate) {
        self.isScrolling = NO;
    }
    NSLog(@"%@scrollViewDidEndDragging", self.isScrolling ? @"" : @"-");
}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    self.isScrolling = NO;
    NSLog(@"-scrollViewDidEndDecelerating");
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{   
    self.isScrolling = NO;
    NSLog(@"-scrollViewDidScrollToTop");
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    self.isScrolling = NO;
    NSLog(@"-scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation");
}
```

Now use the appropriate delegate and call your method.

### *Don't forget to add delegate to your scrollview.*

---

### Edit 2

To add delegate for scrollview, write below line

```
myScrollview.delegate = self;
```

Comment: But how to make this auto trigger based on an event?

Comment: @Digitester : based on which event? could you provide me more details so that I can help you?

Comment: I want the piece of code in my main post to trigger when the UIScrollView gets scrolled.

Comment: @Digitester : does that meant you want to call one method if scrollview gets scrolled?

Comment: Yes, everytime the scrollview gets scrolled I want to call one method.

Comment: how to add delegate to my scrollview?

Comment: @Digitester : in viewDidLoad write `myScrollview.delegate = self;`

Answer (score 0):

`- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` is a **UIScrollViewDelegate**'s method. It will be called automaticaly. 
For that, you have to set the delegate for your UIScrollView as the current ViewController. Set this in your `(void)viewDidLoad` :
`self.myScrollView.delegate = self`.
And on the .h your View Controller has to implement the Protocol <**UIScrollViewDelegate**>:
`@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>`.
Now include the method `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView*)scrolling` on the .m and make the  implementation.